# Generating .Net classes from an existing MongoDB instance

Tags: asp.net, mongodb

We are building an ASP.NET front end for a pre-existing MongoDB database.  What are our options for providing a strongly typed experience to the ASP developers in this situation?  Here are some options I can think of:

1. Manually create classes in .Net with names & fields matching those of the corresponding MongoDB collections.
2. Find a great tool that generates .Net classes from an existing MongoDB instance...?
3. Punt.  I.e., stick with the Document and Field types exposed by one or more of the available MongoDB clients for .Net and call it a day.

The first option doesn't feel great, given that developers in the Microsoft world are used to something more automatic.

The second option is more interesting, though the nature of MongoDB might make it hard for the community to have created such a tool.  (I.e., "schema" can vary across documents in the same collection.)

The last option worries me because it seems to imply giving up on the easiest .Net API experience (the one offered by MongoDB.Driver, which I understand is a facade on top of MongoDB.Driver.Core).

Suggestions?

Thanks,
B

Answer (score 0):

**Choose option 1.**

Understanding, implementing and crafting the data model (or the domain model, or the DAL models, or whatever architecture you choose) is *very* important, and, like the map is not the territory, **the database scheme is not the model** (and it can't be inferred from the schema) [assuming there *is* a consistent structure from which one can infer the schema to begin with]

> The second option is more interesting, though [...] "schema" can vary across documents in the same collection

That is one argument why that might not be a great approach. Another one is that there's no 1:1 mapping from MongoDB data types to .NET. For instance, a `decimal` is, by default, stored as a string (to prevent normalization, among other things), but it can also be stored as a double, for example - that comes with the ability to do range queries in the database, but doesn't come with the precision of decimals. Dictionaries can be stored as list of lists, list of objects, and so on... Likewise, an `ObjectId` can be represented in .NET as `ObjectId` (strong typing, but introduces a dependency on the MongoDB driver), or as a string...

> Punt. I.e., stick with the Document and Field types exposed by one or more of the available MongoDB clients for .Net and call it a day.

.NET developers are used to working in an environment of strict typing, and it makes about every operation hugely cumbersome... Add 0.2 to a string? Oh wait, I can use `Double.Parse`! Oh wait, I do this often, let's write a class... Even worse for nested documents, containers, etc.

> The first option doesn't feel great, given that developers in the Microsoft world are used to something more automatic.

I shun tools that create code: If you think of object-oriented development, why would you want to **leave the creation of the** by far **most important set of classes**, those that carry state, **to a tool**?